# Handle click on a html element in angular 4 like jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angular

In jQuery we can handle click on element without write anything in view:

```
$("#tableId thead tr th").on("click", function() {
  console.log('click on TH');
});
```

Is it possible do something the same in Angular 4?

Comment: No. You can add `(click)="..."` to an element and generate such elements using `*ngFor="..."` to get the click handler added everywhere.

Comment: you can aosi use jquery in your component .. it's not very nice .. but you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by HostListner (MouseDown) Event, where when your mouse down event is fired it calls listner event where you have to find taget element as below:

**You can get required element by Class, ID, Tag as per your requirement**

i.e. (event.target.className=="xyz")

```
import { Component, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.RegisterMouseDown();    
}

RegisterMouseDown() {
    this.el.nativeElement.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.OnMouseDown.bind(this));
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener("mousedown", this.OnMouseDown.bind(this));
}

OnMouseDown(event:any) {
    if (event.target != null && event.target=="th") {
        //user has clicked on th
    }
    else if (event.target != null && event.target=="img") {
        //user has clicked on img
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

HTML

```
  <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
         <th id="elementId"></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
    <table>
```

TS

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'elementId')
       console.log('Click...')

  }
```

But this will listen to all the click event in the html we have to check based on the element id

Answer (score 0):

Try like this this:

```
<button (click)="myEvent($event)">My Button</button>

export class AppComponent {

  myEvent(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

Comment: I knew it, I want to not write anything in `View`

Answer (score 0):

this is how you invoke click function in Angular 2/4

```
<button (click)="clickMe()">Hit me</button>
```

Comment: I knew it, I want to not write anything in `View`